# Given a graph, can we delete exactly k edges and the minimum degree of remaining graph is at least 4

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Given a graph, can we delete exactly $k$ edges to make the minimum degree of remaining graph at least $4$?

Or given a graph what is the maximum number of edges can we delete to make every vertex in remaining graph has at least 4 degrees?

Comment: I was able to reduce this question to a problem about bipartite graphs. But then I couldn't solve the problem with bipartite graphs, so I got curious and [asked a question about it myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268922/).

Comment: Can you explain the reduction? I haven't seen it yet...

Comment: Actually, now that I try to explain it, I've found a flaw in my argument; it can be fixed, but then it's actually a slightly more complicated bipartite matching problem we get.

Comment: Take the bipartite graph with one side $E(G)$ and the other $V(G)$. Also, for every $vw \in E(G)$, draw a red edge $(vw, v)$ and a blue edge $(vw,w)$ - the color is arbitrary. Next, replace every $v \in V(G)$ by $\deg v - 4$ copies of $v$. Then we want to find a maximum "2-to-1 matching" where every $e \in E(G)$ is assigned a red edge and a blue edge - the colors are what I was missing earlier.